# Matlab Plotting by Conditional Statements

Tags: matlab

I am attempting to plot the wave equation for a single time step, t, in matlab based on an array of x that are passed into a function, u.

I am not very familiar with matlab and am not sure if this is the proper way to iterate through all x values and plot them. The process does not seem entirely similar to something like python and matplotlib.

EDIT: This code does not seem to be executing properly, how then can I iterate through the array and plot? ex: for element in x: do function

Thanks,

```
% defining the bounds of my x values

x=-10:.02:10;

% defining my time step, t  
t = 1;


x1=[0 0];

y1=[-0.01 0.01];

x2=[-10 10];

y2=[0 0];


% defining some constants to make below equation simpler
xpt2= x + t;

xmt2= x - t;


% plotting based on the values of x - should iterate through the array?
if abs(x) > 1

  u = 0.5 .* ((-(xpt2) .* exp(-abs(xpt2))./abs(xpt2)) + ((xmt2).*exp(-abs(xmt2))./abs(xmt2)));

  plot(x,u,x1,y1,x2,y2);

  xlabel('t=1');ylabel('u');

else    
  u = 0.5 .* abs(xpt2) + 0.5 .* abs(xmt2) + 0.5 .* (-(xpt2) .* exp(-abs(xpt2)./abs(xpt2)) + ((xmt2).*exp(-abs(xmt2))./abs(xmt2)));

  plot(x,u,x1,y1,x2,y2);

  xlabel('t=1');ylabel('u'); 

end
```

Comment: what is the error? what do you expect?

Comment: no need to make iteration.. however, I believe your calc. `u` incorrectly in `else` since `if` doesn't execute in this code.

Comment: the if does not execute? How then would I cause it to execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code may not solve your issue but it may help you to find the error. I expect the error in the `else` part.

I use for loop to make if-clause work while @slayer way is more professional to work without a loop.

```
% defining the bounds of my x values
close all
clear 
x=-10:.02:10;
% defining my time step, t  
t = 1;
x1=[0 0];
y1=[-0.01 0.01];
x2=[-10 10];
y2=[0 0];
% defining some constants to make below equation simpler
xpt2= x + t;
xmt2= x - t;
% plotting based on the values of x - should iterate through the array?
for i=1:length(x)
    if abs(x(i)) > 1
        u(i) = 0.5 .* ((-(xpt2(i)) .* exp(-abs(xpt2(i)))./abs(xpt2(i))) + ((xmt2(i)).*exp(-abs(xmt2(i)))./abs(xmt2(i))));        
    else
        u(i) = 0.5 .* abs(xpt2(i)) + 0.5 .* abs(xmt2(i)) + 0.5 .* (-(xpt2(i)) .* exp(-abs(xpt2(i))./abs(xpt2(i))) + ((xmt2(i)).*exp(-abs(xmt2(i)))./abs(xmt2(i))));
    end
    %display step by step
    plot(x(1:i),u)
    hold on
    plot(x1,y1)
    plot(x2,y2);
    xlabel('t=1');ylabel('u');
    pause(1/1000)
end
plot(x,u)
hold on
plot(x1,y1)
plot(x2,y2);
xlabel('t=1');ylabel('u');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of issues with your code.

1) Your conditional is on a vector so how can you check a conditional for every point in your vector? Well you can't this way.

2) You are taking the `abs()` of a vector but it looks like you want the negative parts to be accounted for? The `abs([-1 0 1])` will return output `[1 0 1]`, which makes your entire vector positive and remove the negative parts.

Now I see why you were asking for a `for-loop` to check the condition of every x variable in the vector. You can do that with:

```
for ii=1:numel(x) % This iterates through the vector
    x(ii) % this accesses the current index of ii
end
```

But you still don't need a for loop. Instead use a conditional vector to keep track of the neg and pos points in x like:

```
idx_neg = x < 0; % boolean of all negative points in x
```

Then use the `idx_neg` on the vector you want the equation to be applied to. And the invert of the idx for the positive values like:

```
u = zeros(1, numel(x)); % initialize empty vector for storage

% for positive x values, use ~idx_neg to find the pos points
u(~idx_neg) = 0.5 .* ((-(xpt2(~idx_neg)) .* exp(-abs(xpt2(~idx_neg)))./abs(xpt2(~idx_neg))) + ((xmt2(~idx_neg)).*exp(-abs(xmt2(~idx_neg)))./abs(xmt2(~idx_neg))));

% now apply to neg points in x:
u(idx_neg) = 0.5 .* abs(xpt2(idx_neg(idx_neg))) + 0.5 .* abs(xmt2(idx_neg)) + 0.5 .* (-(xpt2(idx_neg)) .* exp(-abs(xpt2(idx_neg))./abs(xpt2(idx_neg))) + ((xmt2(idx_neg)).*exp(-abs(xmt2(idx_neg)))./abs(xmt2(idx_neg))));
```

I didn't check for syntax errors but this is basically what you are looking for.